# img src dissapear when i enter <a href > and and go back to main page.(only mozilla firefox)

Tags: html, css

When i open the main page, everything works perfect, but if i enter a other page, one of my a href, and when i go back to mainpage, my divclass="bild" dissapears, BUT its just on mozzilla firefox.

```
<div class="logo"><img src="pricklogo.png"></div>

<div class="linje" style="float:left;"><img src="linje.png"></div> 

  <div class="meny"> 
   <ul id="avmenu" >
     <li> <a href="first.html">Hem</a></li>
     <li><a href="omoss.html">Om oss</a></li>
     <li><a href="galleri.html">Galleri</a></li>
     <li><a href="fourth.html">Kontakt</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="bild"><img src="bildlogo.png"></div>
```

my css

```
img 
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
div.wrapper {
    max-width: 1100px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.logo
{

    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.meny
{
    background:#000;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    width:495px;    
}

ul#avmenu {

font-size: 100%;
display:block;
}

ul#avmenu li {
padding-right:46px;
display: inline;

}  
ul#avmenu li a {
    border-radius:5px;
padding: 2px 10px;

color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.bild
{
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: Please check with your browsers development console if that `div` really is missing.

Comment: I dont understand what u mean

Comment: Things do not suddenly vanish like this. So usually one starts by trying to track the issue down, by limiting the area where the problem might actually be. In this case the first step would be to check the html markup loaded in the browser when you have the problem and check how that looks like on a technical level. Easiest for this is to use the browsers "development console". In firefox hit F12 and take a look around in there. It helps to see what is really going on. This will be one of the standard tools you use when digging into web programming...

Comment: oh ok thank you, i just realized, the only picture dissapears is the one i want, i just downloaded a picture with exact same heigh and width, and its working flawless

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it using both firefox and chrome, found ok. Can you specify which link disappear? also use alt tag with every image.

Comment: <div class="bild"><img src="bildlogo.png"></div> this one disspers, it disspears if i enter a href or if i ctrl zoom my page, and refres it to

Comment: could it be something with the width? my wrapper is 1100 px, but picture is 1095px?

Comment: try it using small image, then it will be clear to you.

Comment: i just realized, every image works expect that one. is it to big?

Comment: btw, i downloaded a image from google, with exact same heigh and width, and its working perfect...

Comment: then it's for your image, use new image or edit this image using photoshop.